# Codificar imagen en base64 Java

Tags: java, string, post, base64

Estoy intentando convertir una imagen en un `String` *base64* (necesito enviarla mediante *POST*) y no lo consigo. Utilizo la siguiente instrucción:

```
String imgDS = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(".\\imagen.png")));
```

Es una imagen grande con alta resolucion (2,2MB), por lo tanto genera un `String` muy grande (2 millones de caracteres).

Cuando depuro, observo las variables y ocurre una cosa rara. la variable "stringNormal" si que tiene su valor al lado, pero la variable imgDS no. Pero al pinchar encima si que aparece debajo su valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta variable necesito enviarla mediante un *POST*, pero al enviarla el servidor la recibe vacía.

¿Alguien sabe que ocurre?

Gracias

Comment: No es que no la vea, le es imposible mostrar los dos millones de caracteres al lado de la variable imgDS, intenta poner una validación antes de mandarla al servidor para saber si va vacía o no.

Comment: Cuando es muy larga aparece un trozo seguido de puntos suspensivos

Comment: El contenido si está en tu variable en base 64,  para sersiorarte agrega una validacion a tu variable :

 if(!imgDS.equals("") && imgDS != null){...}

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
path.append("ruta de tu imagen");
String imageBase64 = null;
byte[] base64EncodedImage= null;
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
try {
    base64EncodedImage = loadImage64(path.toString());
    if(base64EncodedImage != null){
        imageBase64 = encoder.encodeBuffer(base64EncodedImage);
        if(imageBase64 != null && !imageBase64.trim.equals("")){
            //La envías a tu servidor
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    
}
```

Aquí lo cargas y lo conviertes a base64, haciendo sus respectivas validaciones:

```
public byte[] loadImage64(String url)throws Exception{
        
    File file= new File(url.toString());
    if(file.exists()){
        int lenght = (int)file.length();
        BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte[] bytes = new byte[lenght];
        reader.read(bytes, 0, lenght);
        reader.close();
        return bytes;
    }else{
        log.info("Recurso no encontrado");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Verificas que el archivo exista y lo cargas en un `byte[]`.