# ¿Guardar imagenes en SQLite?

Tags: java, android, imagen, sqlite

Quería saber cuál es la forma de guardar imágenes (fotos de negocios) en la base de datos SQLite. Estoy con una app que muestra todos los negocios de la ciudad donde vivo.

Éste es el código que crea la tabla:

```
  public static final String TABLE_CREATE =               //METODO PARA CREAR TABLA
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NEGOCIOS + " (" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_NOMBRE + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_DIRECCION + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_DESCRIPCION + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_CATEGORIA + " TEXT " +
                    ")";
```

¿Qué tipo de dato puedo utilizar para almacenar una imagen? y ¿cómo la inserto?

¿En mi constructor de datos, retornara una imagen de que tipo de dato?

Este es mi código:

```
public class Negocio implements Serializable {
    long id;
    String nombre;
    String descripcion;
    String domicilio;
    String categoria;





    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getDomicilio() {
        return domicilio;
    }

    public void setDomicilio(String domicilio) {
        this.domicilio = domicilio;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String toString() { return nombre ; }
}
```

Para insertar los datos los hago de forma manual:

```
private void createdata(){
        Negocio negocio = new Negocio();
        negocio.setNombre("La buena atencion");
        negocio.setDomicilio("H Yrigoyen");
        negocio.setDescripcion("Carniceria, los mejores cortes");
        negocio.setCategoria("carniceria");
        dataSource.create(negocio);

        negocio = new Negocio();
        negocio.setNombre("Citadella");
        negocio.setDomicilio("H Yrigoyen");
        negocio.setDescripcion("Panaderia del centro con buenas masas");
        negocio.setCategoria("panaderia");
        dataSource.create(negocio);


        negocio = new Negocio();
        negocio.setNombre("La union");
        negocio.setDomicilio("H Yrigoyen");
        negocio.setDescripcion("Panaderia que abre poco dias");
        negocio.setCategoria("panaderia");
        dataSource.create(negocio);

        negocio = new Negocio();
        negocio.setNombre("Electronica John");
        negocio.setDomicilio("Alem");
        negocio.setDescripcion("De todo");
        negocio.setCategoria("electronica");
        dataSource.create(negocio);

        negocio = new Negocio();
        negocio.setNombre("La maga");
        negocio.setDomicilio("Roca");
        negocio.setDescripcion("comidas rapidas");
        negocio.setCategoria("Casa de comida");
        dataSource.create(negocio);
    }
```

Quería agregarle una imagen o logo de negocio por cada negocio que voy a hacer, estos serian unos 100 negocios aproximadamente. Escucho recomendaciones, y ayuda ya que nunca trabaje con imágenes en SQLite. Gracias!!

Comment: en las base de datos no existe una forma de guardar una imagen como archivo, lo que puedes hacer es crear un método que convierta tu imagen en base64, de esta manera podrás guardar el formato de la imagen en la base de datos.

Comment: La recomendacion es que no guardes la imagen en la db, guardes el archivo y la ruta en la db a dicho archivo, SQlite es una base bastante chica como para guardar imagenes. Aunque podes usar un campo de tipo BLOB

Comment: @MerlingSamuelSobalvarro me podras comentar que es base64?

Comment: @gbianchi se podra guardar la imagenes en la carpeta Drawable y con un string guardar la ruta?

Comment: Ahora que miro bien, podemos discutir esto durante horas. Las imagenes no deberian estar en el servidor? mas alla de eso, las podrias guardar donde quieras. Base64 es una forma de codificar archivos para que parezcan strings. Buscalo en google.

Comment: @gbianchi Bueno chicos gracias por la info.

Comment: puedes checkear en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64231/codificar-imagen-en-base64-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En SQLite 3, puedes definir la columna con afinidad `BLOB`, que es acrónimo de ***B**inary **L**arge **Ob**ject* y, como su nombre implica, su finalidad es almacenar información binaria, como una imagen en el formato de tu elección.

La adaptación al código de creación de la tabla quedaría, entonces, algo así:

```
public static final String TABLE_CREATE =               //METODO PARA CREAR TABLA
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NEGOCIOS + " (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_NOMBRE + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DIRECCION + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DESCRIPCION + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_CATEGORIA + " TEXT " +
                COLUMN_IMAGEN + " BLOB " +
                ")";
```

En java, este campo puede representarse como un arreglo de bytes. El arreglo es, por definición, de longitud variable. Debes entonces, añadir un miembro a tu clase que representa un negocio, para que contenga un arreglo de bytes que es la imagen.

Un ejemplo, adaptado del [tutorial de SQLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/), para leer la imágenes del disco, quedaría como este:

```
private byte[] readFile(String file) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(file);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (int len; (len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            System.err.println(e2.getMessage());
        }
        return bos != null ? bos.toByteArray() : null;
    }
```

Con esta rutina en mano, la preparación de cada *negocio* podría quedar como sigue:

```
    negocio = new Negocio();
    negocio.setNombre("Electronica John");
    negocio.setDomicilio("Alem");
    negocio.setDescripcion("De todo");
    negocio.setCategoria("electronica");
    negocio.setImagen(readFile("/home/juan/imagenes/logoJohn.png"));
    dataSource.create(negocio);
```

Debes tener en cuenta que un BLOB tiene un tamaño máximo en SQLite, que no puede almacenar cantidades grandes de datos en cada fila. Encontrarás más información en la sección [maximum length of a string or blob](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length) del documento *Limits in SQLite*